# Swimming pool as water barrel for irrigation

Tags: water, drainage, irrigation, rain

I have a 60 year old concrete swimming pool still in good condition but not used as a pool for 20 years. It is now a nature pool good for fireflies, bats, toads, ducks, etc.  The original chain link fence is covered with ivy.  The problem is that a pool collects rainwater and needs to leak away the extra water.  Mine has "leaked" on a wooden floor of a wooden garden house for 60 years and I am now fixing that damage.  The solution is I need irrigation on a lower slanted part of the property 165 foot strip of flowers along the sidewalk to my property.  So using the water from one problem to fix the drought on another problem is my plan.  All drip irrigation methods however are engineered to use the least amount of water.  I need to use the most amount of water without "souping up" the flower bed.  For example, filling the pool with my very low city pressure (maybe 45 lbs) used to take 1 hour per inch.  Draining with only gravity pressure and restrictions will be much slower!  I don't want the pool to drain continuously because I have lots of rain and then 2 or 3 weeks with no rain resulting in my sandy soil becoming extremely dry.  I will use a valve to open and close the system.  I can use the top foot of water and would like to put 2 inches at a time on my flower bed only when it is needed.

Luckily I already have an underground 1 1/2 drain pipe from the pool exiting at the base of the 165 foot slope I want to irrigate.  O.K. it sure would be easier if it exited at the top but that is not the case.  The top of the slope is still 3 feet lower than the top of the pool water.  I can plan forever but I will still need to experiment with hole placement and sizing.  If anyone has done anything remotely similar, can you advise me on number of holes, size of holes, size of drip pipe etc.?

My plan at the moment (to do in the spring) is this.

- Starting at the low end (total slope about 3 1/2 feet) 40 feet of 1 1/4 pipe with 5/64 in. holes
- then 40 feet of 1 in. pipe with 3/32 holes
- then 40 feet of 3/4 in. pipe with 7/64 in. holes,
- then 45 feet of 1/2 in. pipe with 1/8 in. holes.

All holes would be 1 foot apart and then more holes could be added or holes enlarged as needed...

Anything I'm missing here?  Or any actual experience with gravity drain holes?

Comment: Plants do okay if they get about an inch of water over area per week.  So you would want to drop an inch of pool area per week to the same size area of plants(if no rain).

Comment: Around here, the local authorities use UAV's and imaging cameras to look for "green pools" that are ill-maintained (not enough chlorine, stuff growing, the green is algae but the real concern is mosquitos / West Nile etc.)  The city brings the hammer down on the homeowner, which during the real estate bust was usually the bank, in which case the city went in and fixed their pool and charged the bank for it.  All that to say, there may be city/regulatory issues with having a pool with water dechlorinated enough to water plants.

Comment: It's unclear to me what, specifically, you're asking. Gravity drains are subject to specific physics so, in a sense, "it is, what it is". I think, as you stated, that it would require experimentation in your specific situation to know for sure.

Comment: Leaves, etc, are going to get into the pool and obstruct your holes; I would not worry about what size they are. You will need some strainer of filter to prevent the pipes and holes from plugging.

Comment: We have unchlorinated pool water for 20 years with no mosquito problems.  I'm unsure why but I believe it has to do with temperature.  Whereas tire swings, eavetrough lows, etc. quickly warm up and cause mosquitos, the 7 foot deep inground pool never warms up that much.  It is overgrown with vines and small trees so very shaded.  It is shaded even more by duckweed, etc. growing on the surface.  The outlet comes from the bottom of the pool and attracts no debris unless pump suction is used, but I would certainly design both ends of the distribution pipe to open for flushing.

Comment: Yeah, for sure I would design the pipe distribution with screw-in orifices so you can change them at will. Seems like no matter what you design on paper, you'll find it does what it does.